# Click an element with tag <a> using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in python programming so I hope you can help me.

I would like to know how can I click this element using selenium

```
    <a class="dropdown__list-item o__hoverable layout__box o__centers-vertically">
            <svg class="interface-icon o__standard o__standard__download-conversation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M6.73 14l.97"></path></svg>
            <span class="layout__box o__flexes-to-1 u__pl__x2">
              Export conversation as text
            </span>
          </a>
```

Im trying using the xpath but it fails

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popper-ember908"]/div/div/div/a/span').click()`

What I'm doing wrong? it should export a txt. doc

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what is wrong with just the code. Please add if there is any error. Also which element tag are you targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the last part of the xpath from "spam" to "span." I think it's just a typo.